# What the jQuery function need to add?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Good day! Help me please with the following question:

We have HTML structure

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Submenu</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
</ul>
```

and JS jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".cat-menu ul li ul").hide();
 $(".cat-menu ul li ul li ul").hide();
 $('.cat-menu span').click(function() {
  $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
  return false;
 }).next().hide();
 $('.cat-menu ul li ul li ul li:last').toggleClass("last");
});
```

Tell me what to do to the script did not block these links, and processed by the event click only those links in which LI has a submenu?

Comment: you might use http://jsfiddle.net/ to play around with it...

Comment: I'm not following the issue...your click handler is for `<span>` elements...of which there aren't any in your markup :)

Answer (score 0):

there is the jquery function 
[HAS](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to accomplish. Would it be possible to extend your question or clarify, perhaps by adding a bit more of the outer HTML code?

Comment: I need to make the script, witch will recognize the real links by himself. I just need to now how to make it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to create a menu with submenus that will show when the menu item is clicked. Using your HTML structure, this is how I will do it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("ul#menu li > a").click(function() {

    $(this).parent("li").children("ul").slideDown("fast");
    $(this).parent("li").siblings("li").children("ul").slideUp("fast");

});
$("ul#menu ul").hide();
```

});